# Javascript generate random string /characters

Tags: javascript, string, random, character

I need some easy code that make alert when generated unique 16 numbers must be 0-9 numbers

Comment: i look at this link and i voted answer but it doesn't count

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object to store numbers, uppercase, lowercase strings; pass an array referencing properties names of object to `rand`, use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to concatenate into single string. Change `60` to accumulated string `.length`

```js
function rand(filter, length, current) {
  current = current ? current : '';
  var types = {
    number: "0123456789",
    uppercase: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ",
    lowercase: "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  };
  var r = (filter[0] === "all" ? Object.keys(types) : filter).reduce((s, t) => {
    s += types[t];
    return s
  }, "")
  return length ? rand(filter, --length
  , r.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length)) + current) : current;
}
alert(rand(["number"], 16));
alert(rand(["number", "uppercase"], 16));
alert(rand(["all"], 16));
```

Comment: thanks for the code, i tried it on js fiddle but nothing happens i am still learning javascript

Comment: _"i tried it on js fiddle but nothing happens"_ Have you tried stacksnippets? Can you post link to jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oco87pbu/ here is jsfiddle, snippet have some error

Comment: @JackZaraf Replaced arrow function `()=>` with `function(){}` at `.reduce()` call https://jsfiddle.net/oco87pbu/1/

Comment: thanks now numbers work great, can you  help me also with uppercase letters and number combined to make 16

Comment: You can use the same call as demonstrated at stacksnippets `alert(rand(["number", "uppercase"], 16));`

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.random():

```
function rand() {
    n = Math.random()*1e17;
    return (n+"").substr(1,16);
}
```

Basically generate a random number between 0 and 1, multiply it by 1e17 to get 17 digits, then take the last 16 digits. Do this because if you just take the first 16 random digits, the first digit could be 0 and not get converted to string (because leading 0's on an integer are not preserved). So make 17 instead, and take the back 16.

Comment: I left out `alert()`. Here is a working fiddle that alerts the number for you: https://jsfiddle.net/xeezp1sx/

Comment: Great :) Glad to hear it.